# CORS support for Microsoft Azure Translate API?

Tags: cors, microsoft-translator

This is a question related to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e856136-9a39-4b98-a53d-7f8bce08e3a6/cors-support-for-bing-translate-api

Does the Microsoft Azure Translate API support CORS now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft Translator Text API](https://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html) appears to at least minimally now support CORS, in that it does at least seem to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in responses:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Origin: http://example.com' \
  'https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?appid=foo&text=hello&from=en&to=de'

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 220
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-MS-Trans-Info
X-MS-Trans-Info: 0642.V2_Rest.Translate.4E779D02
Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2017 09:07:34 GMT

<html><body><h1>Argument Exception</h1><p>Method: Translate()</p><p>Parameter: appId</p><p>Message: Invalid appId&#xD;
Parameter name: appId</p><code></code><p>message id=0642.V2_Rest.Translate.4E779D02</p></body></html>
```

I don’t personally have a valid `appid` to test with—but if you do, I think you’ll find it’ll work:

- if you use `GET` endpoints from the https://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html docs
- if you authenticate using the `appid` parameter instead of the `Authorization` request header

If *may* also work for the https://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html `POST` endpoints—as long as your requests don’t use the `Authorization` request header or set a `Content-Type`.

The problem with those headers is, they’ll trigger browsers to do a preflight `OPTIONS` request:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

And the problem with making calls to those API endpoints that trigger a preflight is, they don’t seem to respond to `OPTIONS` requests in a way that’ll cause browsers to see the preflight as a success.

At https://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/post_TranslateArray I notice the docs say that endpoint expects a `POST` with an `application/xml` or `text/xml` `Content-Type`, so if that endpoint doesn’t respond to preflight `OPTIONS` in the right way, that one won’t work.

That’s because adding an `Content-Type: application/xml` or `Content-Type: text/xml` header to a request will definitely trigger browsers to do a preflight `OPTIONS` before the `POST`.

Comment: Correct! I was using the header `Authorization`. The doc should mention everything you just said

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626890/microsoft-azure-version-2-translate-cors-error-307-temporary-redirect-response for why the preflight response fails.  I suggested there that CORS and V2 used to work though it looks like it might never have.  And as you'll see, there is just one small configuration that is holding it back.